# Strange Issues with CRM 8.x & SQL Server 2017 Reporting

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm, crm

I have used ribbon workbench to fire a plugin via Jscript. The plugin basically gets selected records, builds a text file and updates a field on the selected record, using service.update(x),

After that has been completed, I the try and generate a PDF report of the updated records.

The PDF report is corrected but contains no data apart from a text parameter I pass through from the plugin.

I have checked in my code and can confirm x number of records are updated (simple write out to text log file). I have checked on SQL Server Reporting Services and the report runs correctly and I cannot see any errors in the SQL Server Reporting Services logs.

The report query just selects records with a field Update = true , it's not using any report parameters

When the JScript has completed I get an alert.

I am at a loss as to why there is no data in the report, when I can see in CRM the data has been updated and can run the report in Reporting services. Can anyone make any suggestions?